# ¿Como obtener el indice de una lista?

Tags: java, eventos, interfaz-gráfica

Tengo un programa donde tengo una lista y tengo un `ListSelectionListener` necesito imprimir el indice del elemento que se selecciono de la lista  y lo estoy realizando mediante un `getFirstIndex()` y lo hace solo que con un error, el error es el siguiente selecciono el primer elemento de la lista y me imprime `0` que es el numero que le corresponde selecciono el siguiente elemento de la lista que debería ser `1` pero nuevamente me imprime `0` selecciono un tercer elemento que le correspondería el indice `2` pero me imprime el indice `1`. ¿Como puedo solucionar esto? dejo el código donde se realiza esto y dejo una imagen de como me imprime los indices:
Código:

```
class Esc_lista implements ListSelectionListener {
  @Override
  public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
    if (!lse.getValueIsAdjusting()){
      scan.cargarArchivo(scan.getfilename(e.getFirstIndex())); 
      System.out.println(e.getFirstIndex());
    }
  }
}
```

impresión de lo indices

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La clase `JList` proporciona el método `getSelectedIndex` para obtener dicho indice, en el *listener* se puede acceder a este atributo primero atrapando el componente `JList` con la ayuda de `getSource`:

```
class Esc_lista implements ListSelectionListener {
  @Override
  public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
    JList L=(JList)e.getSource();
    int index=L.getSelectedIndex();
    if(!L.getValueIsAdjusting()) {
      scan.cargarArchivo(scan.getfilename(index));
      System.out.println(index);
    }
    /*if(!lse.getValueIsAdjusting()){
      scan.cargarArchivo(scan.getfilename(e.getFirstIndex())); 
        System.out.println(e.getFirstIndex());
    }*/
  }
}
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias Johnny TB solucionaste mi problema

Answer (score 0):

Por la similitud con otra pregunta que respondí, no debes estar usando un **JList**, sino un **JTable**.

Para lo que buscas existe el método **getSelectedRow()** de la clase JTable. Así que te quedaría:

```
System.out.println(tuTabla.getSelectedRow());
```

Pero como todas las listas, arrays, tablas, etc. comienzan en el índice `0`, le sumamos uno, así:

```
System.out.println((tuTabla.getSelectedRow()+1));
```

Fijate que va todo encerrado en paréntesis para que java entienda que debe **sumar**, si no entiende que debe concatenar.